# HTML Page and Python: Extracting the Body and Dividing Text Within It

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parser

**Big story**

I want to improve a Python application that reads EPUB files. I want to add the option to "memorize" the last place where the reader stopped. Here is [the link to this application on github](https://github.com/rupa/epub/blob/master/epub.py)

---

At the moment, I can save the last words where the user stopped. I want to use these words to find them within the text and show the reader from this place. However, I don't know how to divide text extracted from body of html file and feed it to the formatter.

Here is the excerpt where all this occurs:

```
''' text dump of html '''
class Parser(htmllib.HTMLParser):
    def anchor_end(self):
        self.anchor = None
    def handle_image(self, source, alt, ismap, alight, width, height):
        global basedir
        self.handle_data(
            '[img="{0}{1}" "{2}"]'.format(basedir, source, alt)
        )

class Formatter(formatter.AbstractFormatter):
    pass

class Writer(formatter.DumbWriter):
    def __init__(self, fl, maxcol=72):
        formatter.DumbWriter.__init__(self, fl)
        self.maxcol = maxcol
    def send_label_data(self, data):
        self.send_flowing_data(data)
        self.send_flowing_data(' ')

o = StringIO.StringIO()
p = Parser(Formatter(Writer(o, maxcol)))
p.feed(html_snippet)
p.close()

return o.getvalue()
```

I think that I must intervene in this line

```
p.feed(html_snippet)
```

So guys, could you advise on what I can do now?

With regards